# Issues with 404 pages when inserting posts and changing permalink to /%postname%/

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

The routine below inserts a page, sets permalinks to postname then attempts to update the permalinks settings.

However, when I view the newly created page, I still get a 404 error. The only way to make it go away is to hit the settings > permalinks manager (just merely accessing the page does the trick, i don't even have to save).

What's up with that?

```
//create and insert a post
$my_post['post_content'] = "This is the content";
$my_post['post_type'] = 'page';
$my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
wp_insert_post($my_post);
```

// Including files responsible for .htaccess update
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/misc.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');

```
// Prepare WordPress Rewrite object in case it hasn't been initialized yet
if (empty($wp_rewrite) || !($wp_rewrite instanceof WP_Rewrite))
{
    $wp_rewrite = new WP_Rewrite();
}

// Update permalink structure
$permalink_structure = '/%postname%/';
$wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure($permalink_structure);

// Recreate rewrite rules
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your code, in a plug-in or a theme?

The following plug-in works for me in the latest version of WP. It won't work if `.htaccess` is not writeable, but I don't think you can do anything about that.

```
function my_plugin_activate() {
    $test_post = array(
        'post_title' => 'Lorem ipsum',
        'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing …',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );
    wp_insert_post($test_post);

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate');
```

Comment: Code is in a plugin.  I've got several posts that I'm creating via the script. should I call the rewrite code after each insert statement, or at the very end? Also, I'm using add_action( 'init','activate_plugin_init') but you are using register_activation_hook (what's the difference?)

Comment: You should place the rewrite code after you've inserted all your posts, it should only need to run once. The activation hook function runs when a user clicks the activate link for the plug-in on the Wordpress plug-in options page. The `init` action you are hooking into runs on every request, this is it's description from the documentation: `runs after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent. Useful for intercepting $_GET or $_POST triggers.`

Comment: Richard - I'd like to use register_activation_hook, since my plugin only needs to run once and all inserts are done. No need to duplicate the inserts. So I want to use that rather than init, which sounds more expensive. HOWEVER, my routine only partially runs when I use that method...???

Comment: CORRECTION > HOWEVER, I can't set variables outside the name function and reference them via $global inside the function (unless I'm missing something, which is entirely possible).

Comment: With regards to variable scope in activation functions see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397766/why-wont-my-global-variables-properly-resolve/2398106#2398106

Comment: Richard, if you coded this as a theme, what would you have to do differently?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. As far as I know there isn't anything like `register_activation_hook` for themes. I suppose you would have to go back to using a `init` action function, inside of which you would check/set an option to determine whether or not your theme had been activated.

Comment: Have a look at this post for what might be a better solution: http://wpengineer.com/set-options-on-activation-themes/

Answer (score 0):

Only a suggestion for you...
Disable any WordPress cache functionality before debugging this problem.
Often I have permalinks problems, when using any WP caching.

Comment: Dichev, I'm using wp_cache_flush(); before executing my permalink code. That should do it no?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is on your apache.**

1. Add this lines on /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf.

   < Directory "/var/www/html"> AllowOverride all Require all granted

   ### < /Directory>
2. then on terminal run this : sudo a2enmod rewrite .